# my prime number checker function not working properly

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, primes

So this function is just supposed to return 0 if not prime and 1 if prime. Am I seeing something wrong? for example, when I give it 39, it says it returns 1 although 39 is not a prime.

```
int is_prime(int number){
    if (number == 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    else{
        for(loop_counter ; loop_counter < number ; loop_counter++){

            if(number%loop_counter == 0){
                return 0;

            }
            else{
                return 1;
            }

    }
    }


}
```

Comment: The loop stops at the first iteration, both sides of the `if/else` return. Does that match the logic you intended?

Comment: Remove `else return 1` and place a `return 1` at the end of the function.

Comment: @harold: yes I want it to return 0 if not a prime and a 1 if a prime.

Comment: @Paul ogilvie: Thank you, that worked.

Comment: @KhaledYassen does `number%loop_counter != 0` prove that `number` is a prime?

Comment: @harold yes, am I mistaken?

Comment: @KhaledYassen yes, consider 9, it's not divisible by 2 but also not a prime. Not being divible by a single number is not enough. Actually it looks like you know that because you wrote a loop, but this loop doesn't loop, it exits immediately.

Comment: @harold Oh wait.. I should have started from 3 and then incremented 2 each loop? That would correct. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The first few prime numbers are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23  Notice that 3 doesn't cover everything.

Comment: @KhaledYassen you can do that if you first test whether the number is even, Vlad's answer does that. Of course, it is still important that the loop *continues* if a divisibility test fails

Comment: @harold I saw this other implementation that I do not understand the logic of. the bounds of the loop are loop_counter <=number/2. Would that approach be better? if yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop

```
for(loop_counter ; loop_counter < number ; loop_counter++){
```

there is used an undeclared variable `loop_counter`. If it is a global variable then it shall not be used in the function because at least it is unclear what is its value.

Also within the loop you are interrupting its iterations as soon as `number%loop_counter != 0`. But this does not mean that the number is prime.

And if the user will pass a negative number or zero then the function will have undefined behavior.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int is_prime( unsigned int n )
{
    int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;

    for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}
```

The function at first excludes all even numbers except `2` because even numbers are not prime numbers. And it also excludes the number `1` because the number `1` is not prime by the definition.

```
int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;
```

So within the loop there is no sense to consider divisors that are even.

```
    for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
                                                   ^^^^^^
```

Then within the loop there is a check whether the given odd number `n` is divisible by an odd divisor

```
        prime = n % i != 0;
```

If `n % i` is equal to 0 then the variable prime gets the value 0 and the loop stops its iterations due to the condition in the loop.

```
for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
                          ^^^^^
```

that can be rewritten also like

```
for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime != 0 && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
                          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I do not fully understand the body of your function. Would it be okay if you clarify a bit?

Comment: Suboptimal. Loop should be broken on the first occurrence of `n % i == 0`

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername it does, when ```n % i != 0 ``` returns ```false``` the condition of the ```for``` becomes false and the loop finishes

Comment: I love when you learn something new from simplest questions. Your use of `i <= n / i` is fantastic. I normally use `i <= sqrt(n)`, But I noticed that your method converges to same result without `sqrt()`. Great!!! But maybe `i*i <=n`, since I think calculating `*` is easier `/`.

Comment: @Afshin `i*i <= n` could give the wrong answer due to arithmetic overflow if `n` is greater than the largest square number that fits in an `unsigned int`, so `i <= n / i` is safer. `i <= sqrt(n)` might be faster if the compiler realizes that `sqrt(n)` is loop-invariant and doesn't call it each iteration. But it can be calculated before the loop to make sure. `sqrt(n)` could also be replaced with an integer square root function to avoid introducing floating point math.

Comment: @IanAbbott You are right about overflow, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
for(loop_counter ; loop_counter < number ; loop_counter++){
```

the variable: `loop_counter` is not initialized (nor even declared)

Perhaps you meant:

```
for( int loop_counter = 0; loop_counter < number ; loop_counter++){
```

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. is NOT the fastest/best way to check if a number is prime.  Rather it is a brute force method

The OPs posted code has several problems as discussed in comments to the OPs question, so will not be repeated here.

Now, the proposed code:

```
int is_prime(int number)
{
    for( int loop_counter = 2 ; loop_counter < number ; loop_counter++)
    {
        if(number%loop_counter == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @VladfromMoscow,  What is wrong with the function definition?

Comment: For example for number equal to 1 the function returns 1.

Comment: 1 is not a prime number.  Here is the definition of a prime number:  *A prime number is a whole number greater than 1 whose only factors are 1 and itself. A factor is a whole numbers that can be divided evenly into another number*  see [define prime number](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/prime-number)

Comment: But your function returns 1 for the number equal to 1 or for example 0.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow,   I did not include error checking in the proposed code.  I expect the OP to handle error checking before calling the function.